# Windows Phone - upgrade from 7.8 to 8

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I want to update my developed 7.8 app to 8. After downloading the SKD 8 what changes do I have to apply? Is it just about setting the version to 8?

How do I handle to maintain the old version as well? Is it just about copying the folder and to update just one of it to 8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just open the solution, right-click on project -> upgrade to Windows Phone 8.0. But be careful, your project will not run on Windows Phone 7! You need 2 different projects, one for WP7 and one for WP8.